# moveToElement() to perform a hover action

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can somebody help showing why this is not working?

Page Object:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.CacheLookup;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

    public class NavBarPO {

    WebDriver driver;
    Actions action;

    public NavBarPO(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        action = new Actions(driver);
    }
        @CacheLookup
        @FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "li.menu-item.menu-item-type-taxonomy.menu-item-object-wpsc_product_category.menu-item-has-children.has_children > a")
        private WebElement product_Category;    

        public void hover_Product_Category(){
            action.moveToElement(product_Category);
        }      
}
```

Test:

```
public class OpenDemos {

        @BeforeTest
        public void Initialize() {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/u6028938/Documents/Selenium Java/chromedriver.exe");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Users/u6028938/Documents/Selenium Java/geckodriver.exe");
        }

        @Test
          public void SecondTest() throws InterruptedException {
              WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
              NavBarPO nav = new NavBarPO(driver);
              driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");
              Thread.sleep(3000);
              nav.Hover_Product_Category();
              System.out.println("Successfully Executed Test!");
              Thread.sleep(10000);
              driver.quit();
          }
    }
```

The `nav.hover_Product_Category()` simply does nothing, not even an error. When i use `.click()` instead of `.moveToElement()` the element is clicked and the dropdown that i want is displayed, so the selector is correct.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `perform()` on `Actions` class methods

```
public void hover_Product_Category(){
    action.moveToElement(product_Category).perform();
}
```

Comment: I included `.perform()` and now the test throws the exception `org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: POST /session/d33e2dc4-2b3b-4f1b-a22d-20673c2445b7/moveto did not match a known command`

Comment: @GabrielAbel Where does the exception occurs? on `action.moveToElement(product_Category).perform();`?

Comment: Exactly @Guy. When i include `.perform()`. When it was only `action.moveToElement(product_Category);` this exception didn't happened.

Comment: @GabrielAbel How do you initialize `action`? And what is the import you are using for it?

Comment: @GabrielAbel I see you are using `FirefoxDriver`. Its a [known issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2285). We downgraded `FireFox` to version 45.0.

Comment: Changed to `ChromeDriver` and it worked! Thanks a lot @Guy.

Answer (score 1):

The function `moveToElement` does not work correctly in `FirefoxDriver`. The solution is to change the tests to `ChromeDriver`. If you need to test Firefox you can replace `moveToElement` with `click`.